# Immutable.js' map usage inside react's render's return

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I am going through a article and trying to understand the "react+redux+immuntable" js use case:
https://www.toptal.com/react/react-redux-and-immutablejs

I have a bit of hard time understanding the following part of this article:

Following is Copied from article:

Inside a map callback we get todo, which is an object still in immutable form and we can safely pass it in Todo component.
// components/TodoList.js

```
render() 
{
  return (
  // ….

        {todoList.map(todo => {

          return (

            <Todo key={todo.get('id')}
                todo={todo}/>

          );
        })}
  //  ….
);
```

}

Ques:

1. Why he says "Map Callback" ? Is it a callback here or it is a function being called?
2. Is a Map being created here ? I mean is it something similar to let obj1 = Map({ prop: 'someValue' }); ?
3. What benefit exactly is being achieved by doing this part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`todoList` is an Immutable.js [`List`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List). Which has a `map` function similar to [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `.map(callbackFn)` returns a new `List`, which is the result of applying `callbackFn` to each item in the original `List`. So in this case the result is a `List` of `<Todo>` components. React supports using [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) (List is iterable) as children which is why you can use the result of the `map` directly.

Comment: ok, so I am getting it now, so map here returns all the <Todo>s.

Comment: ok , But how is all this related to immutability ? I mean all the <Todo>s get returned simply or some logic is applied? Or I mean what is being achieved with map here? only iterability?

Comment: You could do exactly the same with a normal array. In this case the props for the Items would be immutable though (the `todo` in the callback is an immutable `Map`) So you would get the benefits when the todos are rendered. The `.map()` is just a way of transforming the List of `todos` to a List of <Todos>

Answer (score 1):

1. The "map callback" is the function passed as an argument to `todoList
   .map`, not like a dynamic object
2. No map is created
3. The idea when using the `map` function on an array is to convert the array into something else. It's a shortcut to express "take this array, and for each element return something and give me the array back". More info on the `map` function [here](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmtt6H4MzXAhUGWxoKHdqeBrYQFggyMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AOvVaw12XNJirv8-3J2POqmbqwb2).